# How to create an asp.net mvc4 action that performs async parallel operation for ajax requests from browser?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, task-parallel-library

I am learning MVC 4 and have this problem:

**What I have working in demo app:**
My Index action of home controller renders a view which shows some empty blocks with loader icon. Meanwhile, I am using jquery ajax call to post some data to my Summary action below and replace the returned partial view in the block of main view and hide the loader icons as well. The client-side code works fine and async is set to true for all calls.

This is a action in my Home controller.

```
[HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Summary(DefaultViewModel defaultViewModel, string reference)
    {
      return PartialView("test", GetView(defaultViewModel, reference));
    }
```

The `GetView` function above, calls some third party rest service and prepares a viewmodel for the partial view.

**Problem:** 
The part that I want to improve is - I want my Summary action of Home controller to listen to those ajax calls from browser asap not after rendering one partial view! For now, this action renders 'x' partial views to the browser, but it takes a long time. I want to minimise that time as if Controller is performing the `GetView` function in background and is immediately available for another request from browser.

For this, I did used asyn-await and `Task.Factory.StartNew` like this:

```
[HttpPost]
  public async Task<ActionResult> Summary(DefaultViewModel defaultViewModel, string reference)
        {
            var viewModel;
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                viewModel = GetView(defaultViewModel, reference);
            });
            return PartialView("test", viewModel);
        }
```

But this is not working for me. I would like to know how can I change my Summary action to listen to ajax request from browser ASAP while doing all the process in the background.

Comment: Describe "not working for me". Is there an error or is it simply no faster than it was before? ASP.NET is multi-threaded so multiple requests should already be running on separate threads. Are you sure the requests are processing one at a time? What you're doing with Task.Factory.StartNew is actually more taxing on the thread pool without any added benefits. If you want to be truly asynchronous (which may or may not help you here), you should change your GetView() code to use an async API to call the web service and return a Task that can be awaited directly by your controller action.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is - your `return PartialView("test", viewModel);` will not be executed until your awaited task is executed.

Comment: @AnthonyChu I understand that but my problem is: all the ajax requests from the browser hit the action when the first partial view is returned. It isn't creating a new thread so its behaving like a FIFO instead of processing all requests in individual threads.